# Same object in multiple collections

Tags: java, object, collections

Is it a good programming practice to keep the same object in multiple collections?

Lets say i have a map, which contains eg.: 500+ elements,

```
Map<String,MyObject> map = new HashMap<>();
```

My application works with multiple connected clients, and i know that each client will almost always use only ±20 known and different elements from this map.

My question is if is it a good idea to create a map for each client which will hold these 20 elements if I want to save some iterations.

Comment: as far as you are comfortable to manage removal of references from all when it is required

Comment: yes i am, in my case i can simply use weakhashmap for removal.

Answer (score 6):

Sure it is. It can even be a way to reuse objects instead of creating a lot of new objects which holds identical data (you would call this a pool of objects or a fly weight pattern).

However, it belongs on the context and you must be sure who and how the objects can be changed. If client A changes an object, it will also be changed for client B. If this is what you have intended, it is perfectly ok.

Comment: Second paragraph deserves some emphasis.  Recognizing that you are now referencing the same object in two or more places and all the power and pitfalls that follow is Object Oriented 101.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a good idea, since it will take less time to get the needed objects from a map, if a map is smaller. As long as you are not cloning those objects, and not having duplicate objects in different maps